# CSS styling not working in a <small> tag with a php script in it

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am having an issue where if I use a bootstrap class to style a  tag containing a PHP script, it works. However, when I use my own styling and use an ID or class to add a color to it, it doesn't. I'm not sure why the php text styles with bootstrap, but not with a regular ID or class. I'm attaching the code and a picture of the PHP variable that has the text that echos if the inputs are empty. I added the style directly to the PHP string and it works, but I don’t know why it can't if it's not setup that way

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <h1 class="text-center">We Want to Hear from You!</h1>
            </div><!--col-->
          </div><!--row-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
              <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                        <small class="small-text"><?php if(isset($firstNameError)){echo $firstNameError;}?></small>
                        <label for="firstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName">
                    </div><!--col-md-4-->
                    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <small class="text-danger"><?php if(isset($lastNameError)){echo $lastNameError;}?></small>
                      <label for="lastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName">
                  </div><!--col-md-4-->
                  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <small class="text-danger"><?php if(isset($emailError)){echo $emailError;}?></small>
                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                </div><!--col-md-4-->
                <div class="form-group col">
                  <small class="text-danger"><?php if(isset($messageError)){echo $messageError;}?></small>
                  <label for="message" class="sr-only">Message</label>
                  <textarea id="message" class="form-control" rows="6" name="message">Message</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                  <button class="text-center btn btn-dark btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" role="button">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <?php 
                    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                      echo "<h4 class='text-success'>Your message has been sent. We will contact you shortly :)!</h4>";
                    }
                ?>
              </div><!--row-->
            </form>
            </div><!--col-->
        </div><!--row-->
    </div><!--container-->
 </section>
```

*-------CSS--------*

```
 * { 
    font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #828282;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Riffic";
    src: url(../Riffic.ttf);
    src: url(../Riffic/rifficfree-bold-webfont.woff);
}

body {
    padding-top: 65px;
    position: relative;
}

#navbar {
    background: #FF9D9D;
}

#navbarBrand {
    font-family: 'Riffic', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border: solid 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

.btn-outline-light:hover {
    color: #FF9D9D;
}

a.btn.btn-outline-light.waysToHelp:active {
    color: #FF9D9D;
}

.waysToHelp {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.waysToHelp:hover {
    color: #FF9D9D;
}

#mainImage {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

section {
    padding: 58px 0 80px;
}

h1 {
    color: #FF9D9D;
    padding: 10px 0 25px;
}

h2 {
    color: #FF9D9D;
    padding: 10px 0 25px;
}

figure {
    max-width: 435px;
}

#figCaption {
    color: #FF9D9D;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: italic;
}

#projectCol {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#message {
    color: #828282;
}

#submit {
    padding: 8px 50px;
    background-color: #FF9D9D;
    border: none;
}

.small-text {
    color: #FF9D9D;
}

footer {
    padding: 20px;
}

footer a {
    color: #FF9D9D;
}

#heart {
    color: #FF9D9D;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

    #mainImage{
        padding-bottom: 50px;
    }

    section {
        padding: 15px 0 20px;
    }

    img {
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    h2{
        margin-top: -70px;
    } 

    #figure1 {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #figure2 {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #figure3 {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1029px) {
    img {
        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }
}
```

[image: this is where I put the styling in the php script rather than having a tag contain it]

Comment: It may help not to look at PHP as interfering with your styling. But possibly a logical error in the PHP code in the implementation of that styling. This is a `html`, `css` issue. You can check your rendered source (usually ctrl + u) to see what the actual rendering is.

Comment: With this code snippet, I can't find why CSS styling isn't applying. It is related to CSS only. But I think your checking logic is incorrect. Here is my suggestion.```if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            if (strlen($_POST['firstName']) > 0) {
                $firstName = validateFormData($_POST['firstName']);
            } else {
                $firstNameError = "<small style='color:#FF9d9d'>* Please enter your first Name.</small>";
            }
        }  ```

Comment: Is there any way to show the live site to check? If yes, I can sort it out immediately.

Comment: I ended up doing what I posted in the picture. I added the CSS as inline style inside the variable like so `$firstNameError = "<small style='color: #FF9D9D;font-size: 80%;'>*Please enter your first name</small>";` I have another issue where IDs are not styling either :/ I'm not sure why all this is happening, but in the end at least I solved it. ANd the site isn't live yet sorry

Answer (score 0):

I have something close to your issue its all about the #FFF some time it not translate in browser correctly when it inside php code (I don't know why )  ,  Please open inspect element in your browser and see did the css apply correctly like `<small style="color:#whatever ; " >` if it  lock like it just clear browser data ( crt+shfit+del ), or you can change the style to class and solve the issue  .

Comment: I ended up doing that code but inside the actual php script, rather than adding a class to the html tag. This is what I did `$firstNameError = "<small style='color: #FF9D9D;font-size: 80%;'>*Please enter your first name</small>";`